# My special characters display as &#8217 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

How do i make my special character display properly on wordpress:

```
  My ' are being converted to &#8217;
```

This is happening for all special characters. Is there a function or plugin to fix?

Comment: Maybe this will help htmlspecialchars_decode() like `echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);`

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars_decode.asp).

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($yourString);
```

According to above mention link the `htmlspecialchars_decode()` function converts some predefined HTML entities to characters.

Comment: How would i use with; <?php the_sub_field('lyrics'); ?>

Comment: Don't know about your code, u can try this function for your string @mario-millions

Comment: This fixed it: <?php echo html_entity_decode(get_sub_field('lyrics')) ?>

Comment: @mario-millions: like html_entity_decode('string', ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')

Comment: It doesn't work for &#8217;